# Is there a Backbone-way to format numbers in the view?

Tags: backbone.js, numbers, format, decimal, points

Is there a special backbone-Way to format numbers? I want to display them with two decimal points, like "2" into "2.00".

Should this be done in the tepmlate?

This is one example from the template:

```
<td><input value="<%- price %>"></td>
```

In Angular.js you can use expressions and filters to achieve this, how is this in backbone?

Comment: I use rivets.js (data-binding) + numeral.js (number formatting)

Comment: Underscore's templates are intentionally pretty simple but you can use a different template system (such as Handlebars which offers custom helpers) if you want.

Comment: Okay, so there is no way to use number formating in Backbone.js? I just want to try out different mvc-libraries so it would be nice to know if Backbone doesn´t offer this out of the box...

Comment: There's nothing out of the box but it is easy to work around if Backbone does everything else you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone is an MVC library, so it's emphasis is on the MVC components of the application.  Formatting is really something you'd want to look at another library for.

One option would be the [Underscore.String](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string#readme) library.  If you're using Backbone, you're also using Underscore, because Backbone requires it.  Underscore.String is an sub-library for Underscore which adds a number of formatting functions, including a number formatting one that you can use like so:

```
_.numberFormat(1000, 2) // == "1,000.00"
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the built in toFixed method.

```
<td><input value="<%- price.toFixed(2) %>"></td>
```